# How to plot this type of graph in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data-frame like this:

```
Hour     Type       Value
1          1          63
1          2          52.1
1          5          53.8
1          4          92.1
1          3          1.4
1          6          4.1
1          2          0
2          1          8.1
2          2          6.1
2          6          0.6
2          5          0.1
2          4          1.09
3          1          9.5
...       ...         ...
23         3          22.5
```

I want to plot a graph like this

[image]

Let me explain:

I want to calculate the mean by per hour, this can be easily done by

`meanValuePerHour= df.groupby('hour')['Value'].agg('mean')`

`rpmByHour.plot.bar(x='Hour', y='Mean Value',title ='Mean Valueby Hour');`

But, Now, I want to add the `Type` variable. Do you see different  colors in each bar? That is how I want to also groupby `Type`.

Something like this
`df.groupby(['Hour','Type'])['Value'].agg('mean')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with `plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)` is what you want:

```
df.groupby(['Hour', 'Type'])['Value'].mean().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]